# Sort by meta key within same day

Tags: wp-query, post-meta, order

I try to build something that can sort posts by day - and within the same day sort them with any meta value (integer) - like popularity or vote or what have you.

So that, in the end, i get today's posts ordered by meta, then yesterday posts by meta, etc, etc...

The WordPress query object allows nice multiple table sorting since v4, including meta data.

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 
    array( 
        'meta_key' => 'my_meta_field',
        'orderby' => array( 
            'date' => 'DESC', 
            'my_meta_field' => 'DESC' 
        ) 
    ) 
);
?>
```

But the `orderby` date seems more like time based, where i would need something day based. My posts are then ordered just by time, ignoring the meta field.

Any help ?

Comment: I think what you need is to sort by date, then "group" by day and then sort by meta field inside each day group. Not sure if that can be done with only one `WP:_Query`.

Answer (score 0):

So here is a quick solution - with a bit of searching over SO and query analyzing : Keep the main query, but add a special filter for ordering.

The filter (in function.php) :

```
function my_posts_orderby( $orderby ) {
  $orderby = 'DATE(wp_posts.post_date) DESC, wp_postmeta.meta_value DESC';
  return $orderby;
}
```

Note the DATE() mysql function that takes the date out of the full time field.

And then, before the loop, run the query thus :

```
<?php add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'my_posts_orderby' ); ?>

<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_key' => '_my_meta_field' ) ); ?>
```

Wich means, call the filter, and then create a query that includes the custom meta field so that it can be sorted.

Then, after the loop, don't forget to call

```
<?php remove_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'posts_orderby' ); ?>
```

failling that no other query will ever work (including displaying a single post)

And that works.